# Firefox on WinXP delivers odd mime-type for uploaded PDF

Tags: firefox, pdf, file-upload, mime-types

When uploading a PDF file from an HTML form, the mime-type Firefox (WinXP) provides in the request header is:

`Content-Type: /home/www/vesta/services/stamper/data/e5456e0699badbe373740d28eca79d09:`

I've seen plenty of `application/pdf` and `application/download`, but never anything like this.

[BTW, I understand that trusting the file extension and the mime-type reported by the browser is unreliable, since it all comes from the client-side. Of course, server-side introspection methods are more reliable. But I'm still interested in this unusual browser behavior.]

Anybody ever seen something like this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Does that path exist on your server? I can't see how FF on a Windows box would be able to figure out the server-side upload path (or whatever) on a Unix system and embed it into the headers, before the upload's even started. There must be something server-side mungeing the headers.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Can you reproduce on a different machine? Which version of FF is it?

Comment: Heh, here's somebody having the same problem (Not the bug report itself, but one of the attachments): https://savannah.cern.ch/bugs/?printer=1&func=detailitem&item_id=42323

Comment: Thanks, folks, for the quick follow-up. @Marc B: Using the LiveHTTP extension, I can see this in the request (!) headers, all before the server gets to see it. @Pekka: FF v3.6.13. Tons of extensions, of course, but can't see any obvious ones that might have an effect. Still, I'll start disabling and see if it helps. Also, I'll try on another machine. Stand by...

Comment: @Pekka: Yeah, I saw that link in my Google searches on the issue. Sure, some comfort to know I'm not alone. ;-) But I'd sure be happier if I could beat this darn thing.

Comment: Same FF vesion on another WinXP machine showing header with type application/octet-stream. After installing Adobe Reader, the same upload shows application/pdf. So, it seems like there is something goofy on my dev machine. It also suggests that the content-type reported by the browser is even more unreliable than I had previously understood.

Comment: Disabled all extensions. Same odd content-type header for uploaded pdf. Guess I'm hosed. Maybe try reinstalling Adobe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this Ubuntu bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/84880) and Mozilla bug #[373621](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=373621).

For some reason, Firefox has been convinced (via `mimeTypes.rdf`) that PDF files have a different MIME type. Delete the offending entry from your `mimeTypes.rdf` file (in your profile directory).

Comment: +1 This sure looks like it. In fact, the `mimeTypes.rdf` file has exactly the `/home/vesta...` weirdness. Where it came from is still a mystery. Thanks!

Comment: This is not OS specific. I saw the same issue for a user on Win 7 and FF8.

Comment: I have this issue in Win 7 and FF 12.

Answer (score 0):

Had it happen to me on a Gentoo Linux, and completely out of the blue as well, without any software updates or anything else. Two days ago I was uploading PDF files as application/pdf, today I see I am sending exactly the same weird content type as the OP.